# Drawer in Tab bar also showing in sliver app bar

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver

[image]I'm trying to learn new widgets of flutter and am stuck in using sliver bar.
I am using Tab bar and a drawer layout on the tab bar and at one tab i am trying to implement sliver app bar but sliver app bar is copying the same drawer layout which i have in tab bar. How to fix this?

### This is tab bar implementation

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// TODO: implement build
return MaterialApp(
  home: DefaultTabController(length: 3,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("App Bar"),
          bottom: TabBar(
            tabs:
            [
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle)),
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit)),
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.print))
            ])),
      drawer: Drawer( child: Column(
        children: <Widget>
        [
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
            title: Text("AC UNIT"),
            onTap: ()
            {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.message),
            title: Text("Message"),
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.print),
            title: Text("PRINT"),
          )
        ],
      ),),

      body: TabBarView(children:<Widget>
      [
        Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
        new SecondWidget(title: "Second widget"),
        new ThirdWidget()
      ]))));
```

and this is third widget implementation

---

```
class ThirdWidget extends StatefulWidget
{
  @override
  _ThirdWidgetState createState() => _ThirdWidgetState();}

class _ThirdWidgetState extends State<ThirdWidget>
{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScrollView(
      slivers: <Widget>
      [
        SliverAppBar(
          pinned: false,
          expandedHeight: 150,
          flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(title: Text("Epic Sliver"))
    )],);}}
```

Comment: You should use either appbar or sliverappbar, SliverAppBar is 'advanced' AppBar. Take a look at this
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar-class.html

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to wrap the `SliverAppBar` with an additional `Scaffold` which has no `Appbar`, so that no icon appears in the `SliverAppBar`.

Example :

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Hello from app bar"),
      ),
      drawer: YourDrawer(),
      body: Scaffold(
        body: NestedScrollView(
          headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
            return <Widget>[
              SliverAppBar(
                ...
              ),
            ],
          },
          body: Text("Hello from body"),
        ),
      ),
    );

}
```

Answer (score 2):

add `automaticallyImplyLeading: false` in your SliverAppBar()